# How can I contract index $d$ in this expression?

Tags: supersymmetry, tensor-calculus

I am trying to contract $d$ in $$([\gamma^{\mu},\gamma^{\nu}])_{b}^{\ d} (\gamma^{5}\gamma^{r}\gamma^{s})_{ad}$$ Since $(\gamma^{5}\gamma^{r}\gamma^{s})_{ad}$ is neither symmetric nor anti-symmetric, I wonder what can I do to contract index $d$? I tried to find some useful identities that might help but failed.

Comment: Note that $[\gamma^\mu,\gamma^\nu]^\alpha_\beta = 2(\gamma^\mu \gamma^\nu)^\alpha_\beta - 2 (\eta^{\mu\nu}I)^\alpha_\beta$ where $I$ is the identity matrix.